# Is it possible to implement it by OWL ontology?

Tags: rdf, owl

Could you please tell me, is it possible to implement such case by just OWL ontology definitions? Or I need to create custom rules for it?

```
IF
  ?doc rdf:type :document
  AND ?doc :state :completed
  AND not exists { ?other-doc :replaces+ ?doc AND ?other-doc :state :completed }
THEN
  ?doc rdf:type :latest-document
```

So the idea is to assign inferred `:latest-document` type to all entities with `rdf:type :document` which have `:state = :completed` and there is no any newer entity with `:state = :completed`.
And I am wondering, if this case is too complex to implement it just by OWL definitions or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "not exists"? If you want it to work as the `NOT EXISTS` keyword of SPARQL, then you cannot do this in OWL. `NOT EXISTS` in SPARQL talks about what is exists in the data, but OWL cannot express anything about what's written in the data. OWL expresses things about what is true in the world. If my ontology does not say that Nikita is a human being, then I cannot conclude that Nikita is not a human being, unless I make additional assumptions that OWL does not make.

Comment: yes you are right, I was thinking that it's possible in OWL to define a type for a dataset except cases when some additional fact exists. but after several days of investigation I realized that `owl:complementOf` doesn't lead to any triples inferred even in addition to other definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! The complicated part is probably how to best describe the relation of being replaced:

```
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .

_:completed-thing a owl:Restriction ;
  owl:onProperty :state ;
  owl:hasValue :completed .

_:replaced-by a owl:TransitiveProperty ;
  owl:inverseOf :replaces .

_:replaced-thing a owl:Restriction ;
  owl:onProperty _:replaced-by ;
  owl:someValuesFrom :completed-thing .

_:latest-thing owl:complementOf _:replaced-thing .
```

This first identifies the class of all completed things via `owl:hasValue`, then defines `_:replaced-by` as the inverse of `:replaces`. This property is transitive (thus by extension `:replaces` is also made transitive).

Next we define a replaced thing, this is anything that is replaced by at least one completed thing defined above. Latest thing is simply anything that is not replaced.

I haven't included the intersection with `:document` that you specified, since it would complicate the core part of the answer. However, it is not needed if `:replaces` and `:state` are already valid only on documents, and it is a simple matter of using `owl:intersectionOf` anyway.

Comment: thank you a lot for the answer!

now it's more clear to me how it should be modelled. unfortunately I was not able to make it working both on Stardog and Ontotext. could you please helm we what I am doing wrong?

Comment: the data is:
```
    :id1 :state :completed .
    :id2 :replaces :id1 ;
         :state :completed .
    :id3 :replaces :id2 ;
         :state :completed .
```

Comment: I tried to use both blank nodes and nodes from my namespace. probably I am doing something wrong, but I don't see any new types appearing for my data. the idea was to have something that I can use for filtering in query to retrieve latest data only (rdf:type?).

Comment: and second question - is it possible to do the same but without making "replaced" property transitive? its purpose is to point to a previous version, probably, "prev-version" predicate name would be more correct for it. so, is there a way to have inferred transitive "replaces" predicate and use it for that rule but without making initial "prev-version" predicate transitive as well? I will really appreciate your help here. I was trying to sort it out by myself but got completely stuck.

Comment: @Nikita Sorry, I didn't write this with a specific reasoner in mind; frankly I have no idea why it wouldn't work. Maybe `_:latest-thing a owl:Class` is necessary. As for the second question, simply make `:prev-version` a subproperty of `:replaces`. It will not be affected by any transitivity then.